# cannot build react native project after react-native-git-upgrade

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I tried to upgrade react-native from `0.49.3` to `0.55.3`. I followed the official [guide][1] and when I ran `react-native-git-upgrade`, I got the following log:

```
git-upgrade info Check for updates 
git-upgrade info Using yarn 1.5.1 
git-upgrade info Read package.json files 
git-upgrade info Check declared version 
git-upgrade info Check matching versions 
git-upgrade info Check React peer dependency 
git-upgrade info Check that Git is installed 
git-upgrade info Get information from NPM registry 
git-upgrade info Upgrading to React Native 0.55.3, React 16.3.1 
git-upgrade info Setup temporary working directory 
git-upgrade info Configure Git environment 
git-upgrade info Init Git repository 
git-upgrade info Add all files to commit 
git-upgrade info Commit current project sources 
git-upgrade info Create a tag before updating sources 
git-upgrade info Generate old version template 
git-upgrade info Add updated files to commit 
git-upgrade info Commit old version template 
git-upgrade info Install the new version 
warning " > react-native-maps@0.20.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@16.0.0".
warning " > react-native-maps@0.20.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native@0.51.0".
warning " > @storybook/addon-storyshots@3.2.13" has unmet peer dependency "@storybook/addons@^3.2.13".
warning " > @storybook/addon-storyshots@3.2.13" has unmet peer dependency "@storybook/channels@^3.2.13".
warning " > @storybook/addon-storyshots@3.2.13" has unmet peer dependency "@storybook/react@^3.2.13".
warning " > @storybook/addon-storyshots@3.2.13" has unmet peer dependency "babel-core@^6.26.0".
warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > react-icons@2.2.7" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > react-komposer@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0".
warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > react-modal@2.4.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0".
warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > react-modal@2.4.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0".
warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > react-treebeard@2.0.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.5.4".
warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > react-treebeard@2.0.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^15.5.4".
warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > mantra-core > react-komposer@1.13.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.3 || ^15.0.0".
warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > mantra-core > react-simple-di@1.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0".
warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > react-komposer > react-stubber@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0".
warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > react-treebeard > velocity-react@1.3.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "@storybook/react-native > @storybook/ui > react-treebeard > velocity-react > react-transition-group@1.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning " > babel-jest@21.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "babel-core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0-alpha || ^7.0.0-beta || ^7.0.0".
warning " > enzyme@2.9.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@0.13.x || 0.14.x || ^15.0.0-0 || 15.x".
warning " > react-addons-test-utils@15.4.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^15.4.2".
warning "react-native > eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4.0.0".
git-upgrade info Generate new version template 
git-upgrade info Add updated files to commit 
git-upgrade info Commit new version template 
git-upgrade info Generate the patch between the 2 versions 
git-upgrade info Save the patch in temp directory 
git-upgrade info Reset the 2 temporary commits 
git-upgrade info Apply the patch 
error: patch failed: .gitignore:51
Falling back to three-way merge...
Applied patch to '.gitignore' with conflicts.
error: ios/MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: does not exist in index
error: ios/MyApp/AppDelegate.h: does not exist in index
error: ios/MyApp/AppDelegate.m: does not exist in index
error: ios/MyApp/main.m: does not exist in index
error: ios/MyAppTests/MyAppTests.m: does not exist in index
git-upgrade WARN The upgrade process succeeded but there might be conflicts to be resolved. See above for the list of files that have merge conflicts. 
git-upgrade info Upgrade done
```

Notice these lines:

```
error: ios/MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: does not exist in index
error: ios/MyApp/AppDelegate.h: does not exist in index
error: ios/MyApp/AppDelegate.m: does not exist in index
error: ios/MyApp/main.m: does not exist in index
error: ios/MyAppTests/MyAppTests.m: does not exist in index
```

These files are now all missing. Despite the message saying it succeeded, trying `react-native -v` yields

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.55.3
```

And now the `MyApp/ios/` directory is missing almost all of it's original files. If I even try `react-native run-ios`, I get `xcodebuild: error: Scheme MyApp is not currently configured for the build action.` Any suggestions would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. For those of you with this problem, all you need to do is delete your android/ios folder and use `react-native eject` which will regenerate the files necessary to rebuild your react-native project. This should be in the official react native upgrading guide IMO.